# Build and use npm package locally

Tags: angular, npm

I made some custom modifications in the ngx-mask package and need to test it locally.

How to overwrite the installed npm package?

Currently the package is declared as a dependency in packages.json file as:

```
"ngx-mask": "^7.8.9"
```

I do prefer not to fork the original package and not to use github for this, if possible.

Comment: The package files must be present inside your node_modules folder. Go and edit them their.

Comment: @Obaid Since Angular 13, there is a caching for the node_modules. Editing files there will cause problems with the cache.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you have made these changes on your machine. (I'm assuming you have)

1. Run a `build` of the `ngx-mask` package that you changed.
2. run `npm pack` from that package's root folder. This creates a `.tgz` zip file of your package with your custom modifications.
3. copy that file into the root (you could put it wherever but root makes things easy) of your project.
4. in your `package.json` replace the version number ngx mask to the following `"ngx-mask": "file:my-packed-file.tgz"`
5. Run an `npm install` using your new `package.json`

you should have your modified copy loaded in as a dependency in `node_modules`.

Comment: Run a build means "npm run build" ? This give me the error "npm ERR! missing script: build"

Comment: "ng build" create the "dist" folder, but "npm pack" then gives the error "npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file."

Comment: So I'm assuming that you've cloned the `ngx-mask` package. If you see inside it's `package.json` then it has no `build` script. Instead it is `"build:library": "ng-packagr -p package.json"`
Try `npm run build:library` when you're in that project's root :)

Comment: Does this work the same way  `npm link` ?

Comment: So I have to do this every time I make a change in the dependency ? Just pointing the dependency in `package.json` to the local folder doesn't work ?

Comment: `npm pack` should not be run from the `dist` folder, that's wrong.

Comment: as the person above mentioned `npm pack` should be run in the parent folder and not the dist folder.

Comment: I have edited my answer to change that point @Alex @ Nikola

Comment: @James So what's the point of `Step: 2`?

Comment: Quite right, I have removed that and clarified the `npm pack` step. @SumitRidhal

Answer (score 24):

### The '**npm link**' command was made for this.

In your *test* repo (where you **use** the *ngx-mask* package) run:

```
npm link /path/to/your/locally/modified/ngx-mask/package
```

This will install your locally modified *ngx-mask* into your *test* repo.

When you are done testing your local version of the *ngx-mask* package, you can simply unlink it. To unlink the local version of *ngx-mask*, in your *test* repo run:

```
npm unlink --no-save /path/to/your/locally/modified/ngx-mask/package
```

If you want to re-install the *registry* version of the *ngx-mask* package run:

```
npm install
```

Comment: One small caveat I had to first uninstall (`npm uninstall <target-package-name>`) the target package I wanted to link from because it was already being used in my test repo (where I use such package) - I guess `npm link /path/to/your/locally/modified/ngx-mask/package` will skip if the package already there. Other than that the steps outlined above worked great. Thanks.

Comment: So wait, what's the order here ? First run `npm-install` for all the other dependencies, THEN `npm link` to supersede the packages from the registry with the local ones ?

Comment: @JoseQuijada the linked package should be respected above the package in your test repo as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

### 'npm install'

`npm link` should be avoided because of different bad behaviours. Read this blog-article for more informations https://hirok.io/posts/avoid-npm-link

Here is an alternative with `npm install`:

1. Build your `ngx-mask` project. You should have a `dist`-folder after that.
2. Add `ngx-mask` to the dependencies of your test-project. Use the current version of `package.json` of `ngx-mask`.
3. Run `npm install --no-save /path/to/ngx-mask/dist`

If you have multiple packages, then you have add them with one command.

```bash
# good
~ npm i --no-save /path/packageA/dist /path/packageB/dist

# not good
~ npm i --no-save /path/packageA/dist
~ npm i --no-save /path/packageB/dist
```