# How to install internal angular lib

Tags: angular, npm-install, angular-library

So my structure is the angular project is like this
project

- project/my-lib
- src/app
- package.json

I have created lib called my-lib it is used in app so i have it as dependency in package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"my-lib": "file:dist/my-lib",
}
```

When i run npm install in the root of the project i get

```
"npm ERR! Could not install from "..\dist\my-lib" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Here is example project on git https://github.com/IvanGavlik/AngularTest. You will get same exception when you run npm install

Also when i try to build lib

```
ng build my-lib
```

I get

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr/package.json'
```

Note I am using angular 9 and i do not want to publish my libaray

Comment: Does your lib have package.json?

Comment: yes. It is like this.

{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.7",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  }
}

and has a lot of peerDependencies

Comment: You probably don't point to library correctly, but from structure you wrote it's hard to find what you did wrong. Did you build your library first? If you want monorepo maybe take a look at https://nx.dev/angular

Comment: Here is example project on git https://github.com/IvanGavlik/AngularTest. We I try to build it I get:  Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr/package.json'

Comment: Hi, It looks like you want to do something very similar to this question. Check out the accepted answer which details steps on using local packages in this way. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560791/build-and-use-npm-package-locally/55560928#55560928

Comment: ¸problem whit this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560791/build-and-use-npm-package-locally/55560928#55560928) is when i first time run a build of lib i need install dependencies first, if lib have a lot of dependencies it will take a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Î found to solution.
In package.json change the path to the lib dependency
form

```
 "my-lib": "file:dist/my-lib",
```

to

```
 "my-lib": "file:projects/my-lib",
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have paths configuration in the [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/IvanGavlik/AngularTest/blob/main/tsconfig.json) :

```json
"paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "dist/my-lib/my-lib",
        "dist/my-lib"
      ]
    }
```

You should be able to import from `my-lib` once the lib built :

```js
import { MyLibService } from 'my-lib';
```

As you are not planning to publish the library, you can skip the build step and change the `tsconfig.json` path to point to source :

```json
"paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "projects/my-lib/src"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What shold i put in the package.json file in dependencies "my-lib": "file:projects/my-lib",

Comment: or the version number "my-lib": "0.0.1"

Comment: `package.json` is only for external dependencies to download with npm, if you have a local library you don't have to add it to `package.json`.

Comment: what about build, is build of app include build of my-lib ?

Comment: Yes, like if it was part of the application sources.
Also while developping, code changes in library will trigger browser refresh, which is very handy while coding.

Comment: ok, but imports can become big mess, I will need to write something like this
import { MyLibService } from 'projects/my-lib/src/lib/my-lib.service'; 
i would like them to be 
import { MyLibService } from '/my-lib/MyLibService; You can see example here https://github.com/IvanGavlik/AngularTest.

Comment: You just need to export what you what to be available from out side the library in the `public-api.ts` https://github.com/IvanGavlik/AngularTest/blob/main/projects/my-lib/src/public-api.ts then import `import { MyLibService } from 'my-lib'` where `my-lib` is the key of the path defined in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr on your node_modules, or run below steps.

1. Remove this line

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-lib": "file:dist/my-lib", // <-
}
```

2. run

```
npm i
ng build my-lib
npm i ./dist/my-lib
```

Comment: problem whit this is when i first time run a build of lib i need install dependencies first, if lib have a lot of dependencies it will take a lot of time