# Creating a NPM Package which needs data from a Composer Package

Tags: node.js, wordpress, vue.js, npm, composer-php

I'm creating a wordpress package which uses acf (Advanced Custom Fields) to get and set the data.

**Additional data about the usage:**

First in your project's config.php file you set the settings for the composer package. Then in wordpress you can call the block "photoplayer". You can give the block some data and the data is accessible in the composer package.

But now comes my problem. The frontend needs to be in vuejs since this is a composer package and vue is a `peerdependency` vue isn't accessible because it's in the `vendor` folder. A hacky way which you don't want to do ever is to install the npm packages inside the package in the `vendor` folder (this will cause more problems because vue uses singleton). So I choose to make a vue package for this with npm.

Now I've just created the frontend inside a npm package, but how will i get the composer packages data to the npm package in the frontend?

I've thought of an API, but I think that that solution is to overcomplex for such a problem.

Comment: Those are very broad questions. What have you tried to resolve your issue? What is your concrete question with that?

Comment: @hakre well I've already solved the problem which was quite simple. In the main project I've installed the 2 packages. The npm package exports a vue component which I can mount to the createapp in the main project. Then the only thing I needed to do was to call the vue component in a template file in the composer package which then can give all the additional data through props.

Comment: Please add it as an answer, best with some short excerpts from this configuration so that it is visible next to the explanation why you did. You can then mark your question answered later on. This will help future visitors including your future self  @Keygun2k1

Comment: Thank you I'll add an answer immediately @hakre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a solution to this problem:**

**Requirements:**

- main project
- npm package (in my case created in vue)
- composer package

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560791/build-and-use-npm-package-locally#answer-55560928) you'll find on how to create and use a local npm package.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994088/composer-require-local-package#answer-39802804) you'll find on how to create and use a local composer package

**First you'll need to install your local packages:**

`npm i path/to/package/package-name.tgz`
`composer require path/to/package/`

The npm package exports a component:

```
import MyVueComponent from "./MyVueComponent.vue";

export { MyVueComponent }
```

This makes it so that we can mount this vue component to the projects createapp:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { MyVueComponent } from "my/package";

const app = createApp({})

app.component('MyVueComponent', MyVueComponent)
app.mount('#app')
```

Now you can use the `MyVueComponent` as a custom html tag within your `#app`. Now in the composer package we create a template file something like `template.php` will do you can name it however you like. Within this template we call the vue component:

```
<my-vue-component
    :name-of-property="'Data you want to provide'"
    :name-of-second-prop="'More data'"
></my-vue-component>
```

Now I've passed some data to the props of the vue component. You can learn how to use props in vue [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html).

In my case showcasing the template is easily done using ACF and wordpress, but rendering a composer template file is a little out of scope here.